# modify the transparency of a background image in android xml

Tags: android, background-image, transparency

Hi i need to put a background image in an activity and this image needs to be a bit transparent because i want to put text over it. how can this be done?
can it be done directly on the xml file and if yes how? 
Is it also possible to do it programmatically and if yes how?
And could you please show me an example.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An XML example would look like

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myimage"
    android:alpha=".75"/>
```

Programatically, you can also set it with

```
int alphaAmount = 125; // some value 0-255 where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque
myImage.setAlpha(alphaAmount);
```

where myImage is an ImageView.

Comment: Attribute "alpha" is only used in API level 11 and higher

Comment: This also worked on a layout that was referencing a back ground img. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `android:alpha`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:
    `yourview.getBckground().setAlpha(INTEGER_VALUE (more than 100));`